# Shorten commands that contain the same preface

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation

Making aliases for commonly used commands is nice if you know what commands you'll use a lot. But sometimes the same command is used several times in a row with different arguments. For example:

```
git fetch --some-option
git do-something-else
git another-command
# ... lots more of the same
```

In this case it would be nice to drop `git` each time. In some cases it may be multiple arguments a command should start with (e.g. `sudo apt ...`).

What software can do this?

---

Note: I saw a project like this trending on GitHub a long time ago but can no longer find it. Naturally it would be nice if someone remembers what I'm thinking of, but anything that fits the description (or is a workable alternative) is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use bash - you can make the following function

`myprefix() { echo -n "> $1 "; while read -r line; do $1 $line; echo -n "> $1 "; done }`

Then when you have a bunch of `git` commands you can issue

`myprefix git`

And press ctrl-c to recover.

Comment: You can insert the function in your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Accepting for now as this is fits the basic idea of what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On your alias since its shell syntax you are free to access command line parameters using $1  $2  $3  to puck parm1 parm2 parm3

```
alias gitdo="git do-something-else $1"    
alias gitand="git another-command $1 $2 "
```

just put these alias definitions into your ~/.bashrc file ... usage would then be

```
gitdo my-parm1
```

Alternative trick to alter prior command is to search for it then do in place edits ... say I just issued

```
git foo bar blah
```

then later in same terminal I can pull back that command either by simply using up arrow key or by doing a command line search

```
ctrl-r foo [enter]
```

which will retrive above to permit the edit and re-issue (ctrl-e to jump to end of line,  ctrl-a jumps to line beginning, or ctrl arrow left right jumps words)

```
git woo bar blah
```

another search trick would be

```
history | grep foo
```

Comment: Thanks--but the ideas is that the aliases aren't generally known ahead of time. For example, say you're suddenly using the `convert` command a lot in one session. It doesn't make a lot of sense to go and create an alias for it (unless using it a ton). You're right though that this adds the ability to supply arguments (which not all aliases would accept).

Comment: Didn't know about the ctrl+r trick. Super helpful! Thanks.